# Call pytest through code and save results to variable or file

Tags: python, pytest

I am calling pytest through my code with `pytest.main()`

Is it possible to save the results from this? Either assigned to a variable or as a file? I know you can do it through the cmd as `pytest > log.txt`, is there something similar when calling it in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect `sys.stdout` to variable `output`:

```
import pytest
import sys
import io

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stdout_bak = sys.stdout  # backup stdout
    sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
    pytest.main()
    output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdout = stdout_bak  # restore stdout

    print(output)
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your help. This is creating a file but it is blank, should it be saving what is in the created in the python debug console by pytest? If not, how would I do that?

Comment: @Sam. I updated my answer. Can you check if it's the correct behaviour now, please?

Comment: This works! Thanks! I added this to save to a File:

`try:
    file = open("log.txt", "w")
    file.write(output)
    file.close()
    print('File saved!')
except:
    print('FILE FAILED TO SAVE')`